# Scrapy not downloading image

Tags: image, download, scrapy

My spider runs but not download images, and I don't have any error showed
in the json file i have all field but images is empty  'images':[]
I don't know how to fix this.

Can someone help me please for downloading files ?

item.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item

class OscarsItem(scrapy.Item):

    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls=scrapy.Field()
    images=scrapy.Field()
```

setting.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'oscars'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['oscars.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'oscars.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE = "./images"


# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
```

pipelines.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class OsacrsPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
        if not image_paths:
            raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
        item['image_paths'] = image_paths
        return item
```

oscars_spider.py

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from scrapy import Selector
from oscars.items import OscarsItem
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline

class OscarsSpider (scrapy.Spider):
   name = "oscars"
   allowed_domains = ["elbi3.com"]
   start_urls = ["https://elbi3.com/fr/algerie/offre/annonce/dz//categorieancetre/locations-immobilieres/"]
   def parse (self, response):
       urls=response.xpath("//a[@id = 'an-title']/@href"). extract ()
       for p in urls:
           url = urljoin(response.url, p)
           yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_annonces)


   def parse_annonces(self, response):
       for annonce in response.xpath("//div[@itemtype='https://schema.org/Product']"):
           yield {
            'Titre': response.xpath("normalize-space(//h1[@class='detail-titre']/text())").get(),
            'Ville': response.xpath("normalize-space(//h2[@class='country-wilaya']/text())").get(),
            'Annonceur': response.xpath("normalize-space(//p[@class='nom-entreprise orange']/text())").get(),
            'Prix': response.xpath("normalize-space(//span[@itemprop='price']/text())").get(),
            'Statut': response.xpath("normalize-space(//p[@class='type-inscription orange']/text())").get(),
            'Description': response.xpath("normalize-space(//div[@itemprop='description']//div/text())").get(),
            'Tel': response.xpath("normalize-space(//div[@class='contact-box']//p[last()]/text())").get(),
            'image_urls': response.xpath("//ul[@id='foo3']//li[1]//img/@src").extract()

                 }
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes image downloads are disallowed in `robots.txt`. Try:

```
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

Comment: Thank you, i have images downloaded, can you explain to me please why this option disable image downloading ?

Comment: Check `https://elbi3.com/robots.txt`. You'll find `Disallow: /upload/` rule and also this is a part of each image path.